# What is the first billiards game ever rules?

Tags: rules, history, match-identification

The picture below is a drawing from [1674 of one of the very first billiard table that I could find](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ground_billiards&action=edit&redlink=1) in wiki said it had no information on this game called [Ground billiards](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ground_billiards&action=edit&redlink=1). Does anyone know or where to find the rules?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not easy, I couldn't find a lot of information but yes, I found a very useful link with the [**rules**](https://sites.google.com/site/madmedievalsciencefair/billiards) of "Ground Billiards".